# Entity Framework 5 System.OutOfMemoryException simple select query on large table using Take()

Tags: c#, .net, out-of-memory, entity-framework-5

I am using entity framework 5 with a simple agent running on windows 2008. My db has a large amount of records (over few millions).

While fetching a few records in db I get a System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. Looking at the server there are dozens of GB of memory available (so def not a hardware limitation) and the process ends when reaching ~1800MB.
My query is quite simple (I am testing if a DateTime flag is NULL) and do a take using the parameter 20.

```
(x => x.myfalg.HasValue == false ).Take(pSampleSize);
```

Why would EF load more records than 20 here. Shouldn't the take restrict the quantity of data loaded?

note : our context is using these two params at init.

```
this.dbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
this.dbContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
```

Comment: What is the geneerated SQL? Use profiler and paste it here

Comment: Have you tried `(x => x.myflag.Equals(null)).Take(pSampleSize)`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, the issues was system related. I do not have the out of memory after fixing my environment.